# SQL Increment based on column count

Tags: sql

So I have a table (Org_Contacts) that will link a contacts table to an organization.

The table is currently setup like this:

```
Organization ID (int)
Contact ID (int)
Priority (int)
```

There may be multiple contacts to an org and I would like to insert the contacts in and based how many contacts are assigned to an org I would like to increment the priority for that contact.

For instance, I have two organizations, **ABC(ID:90)** and **XYZ(ID:91)**.

I have 5 contacts for those two organizations.
**John (ID:10),
Jane (ID:11),
Steve (ID:12),
Bob (ID:13),
Jennifer (ID:14)**

When I add John to the ABC as a Contact I want the priority to start at 1

```
Org_Contacts
------------
90|10|1
```

Next I'll add Jane to the same org as a contact causing her priority to be 2

```
Org_Contacts
------------
90|10|1
90|11|2
```

Following that Steve will be added, but he will be a contact for XYZ

```
Org_Contacts
------------
90|10|1
90|11|2
91|12|1
```

Bob will be next and will be added to ABC

```
Org_Contacts
------------
90|10|1
90|11|2
91|12|1
90|13|3
```

and last is Jennifer to XYZ

```
Org_Contacts
------------
90|10|1
90|11|2
91|12|1
90|13|3
91|14|2
```

I am trying to accomplish all of this in an insert statement. I'm thinking maybe a subquery that uses a count, but I'm not sure as to the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of maintaining the priority within the table it might be easier to calculate it on the fly using ROW_NUMBER (you didn't specify your DBMS, but most support it):

```
select
   Organization,
   Contact,
   ROW_NUMBER()
   OVER (PARTITION BY Organization
         ORDER BY Contact) AS Priority
from tab
```